# Make inner container in flex layout fit screen size

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and css code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7tb6r1n/)

```css
/** CSS Framework: START **/
html {
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
/** CSS Framework: END**/

.inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.very-big-container {
  width: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <!-- I can change everything starting from here -->
  <div class="inner-box">
    <div class="very-big-container">
        Foobar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You see that there is a very big container which doesn't fit a normal screen size. That's why I am using `inner-box` for setting the max width to 100% and for enabling a horizontal scrollbar. The problem is that the scrollbar for the container `inner-box` does not appear. I only have a scrollbar for the whole window. I know that I can fix my problem by removing `display: flex` from `html` and `flexbox`, but unfortunately these properties are coming from a css framework and I cannot change anything about that. So do you have any other ideas to enable the scrollbar for `inner-box`?

Comment: I'm able to scroll from the browser's given scrollbar. Is that not enough?

Comment: @Rojo No, thats not enough. I need the scrollbar for the inner container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reason

`display: flex` declaration in the `html` element enables the flex context for all the direct children of `html`.

As no `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` properties declared, their default values would get applied on `html`.

```
html {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

## Solutions

### Solution 1

Add `flex-direction: column` declaration to `html` element

### Solution 2

Add `width: 100%` declaration to `body` element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: 100vw;`

See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ftbu69nx/)

Comment: Yeah, that kind of solves my issue. But as you might have noticed, there is still a tiny scrollbar for the whole window. This problem even gets bigger, if you have for example a sidebar, like here in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5n6jLmzh/
Any solution for that?

Comment: @MatthewDarton Then add `body { overflow-x:hidden; }` to your css